# node app.jsを実行するとnode.js error: cannot find moduleになる

Tags: node.js, express.js

node.jsをやっていてサーバーを起動しようとnode app.jsを実行しようとすると以下のエラーが出ます。

調べてもmacのものだったりで解決できません。
node.jsが壊れているのでしょうか？
OS は Windows 10 です。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
PS C:\Users\　pcname　\OneDrive\デスクトップ\app.list> node app.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ pcname \OneDrive\デスクトップ\app.list\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: パスに"デスクトップ"が入っていますね。半角英数だけで構成されるパスで実行したらどうなりますか？

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\　pcname　\Downloads\Download mod\mod\app.list\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
と表示されて変わらないです。